# Navigation Bars Design

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

i work on application and done almost every coding and logic part but now i am going to put some effects on navigation bar like in this [Example](http://www.nakeddesign.net.nz/) but i am not well with css so how can i do this in my project

i am currently do this

```
.nav ul li a {
color: #666666;
display: inline-block;
font-family: DinC;
padding-bottom: 60px;
padding-top: 30px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 84px;
}
```

and on hover

```
.nav ul li a:hover, .nav ul li a.active{
background-image: url(images/hover.png);
background-position: left bottom;
background-repeat: repeat;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ;
-moz-transition: all 1s ;
-ms-transition: all 1s ;
-o-transition: all 1s ;
transition: all 1s ;}
```

But through this it will appear at once i want juts like in example link

Here is mine navigation Image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's flash. You could technically do it with a lot of individually animated `<div>`s or pseudo elements, but realistically you're going to have to come up with a simpler effect.

Comment: so it can be done through different divs and apply transition and timing effects?

Comment: Sure, just have 40 different elements animate at 40 different speeds. But it will be a mess and never animate that smoothly.